# Celery worker --exclude-queues option is not affected

Tags: celery, celery-task

I use celery 4.0.2.

I want my celery execute only specific queue. (or exclude specific queue)
So I executed celery as below.

```
celery -A mycelery worker -Q queue1,queue2 -E --logfile=./celery.log --pidfile=./celery.pid &
```

but when I run the code like this, 'testqueue' is consumed very well..!

```
mycelery.control.add_consumer('testqueue', reply=False)
myfunc.apply_async(queue='testqueue')
```

So I change the option as below and execute source code.

```
celery -A mycelery worker -X testqueue -E --logfile=./celery.log --pidfile=./celery.pid &
```

myfunc still run well..

'-Q' option means 'consume only the name of queue',
And '-X'option means 'never consume the name of queue'... isn't it?

What's wrong?

Comment: why you use `mycelery.control.add_consumer('testqueue', reply=False)?

Comment: Its needed to start, pause, stop to consume by my service scenario. Above code is not affected well so I'll use destination option instead of it.

Comment: @hai were you able to figure out why? would be great if you can share your solution. Thanks.